# In SMSS what's the difference between NULL and nothing, in a query result?

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2008

I know this maybe a newbie question, but i'm wondering why I sometimes get NULL in a result, and sometimes it's just totally blank - shouldn't they all be null?

[image]

Comment: "nothing" as you put it is an **empty string** (`""`) - but that's still a **value** (while `NULL` is the absence of a value)

Comment: I've always thought of NULL as "No value has ever been provided " where as nothing may have had a value at one point, but a user has now set it to empty set "".  I also look at nothing in .net terms as an instance of an object hasn't been instantiated.  It's not null; it's nothing.

Comment: Be careful when writing queries which contain clauses on columns that contain 'NULL' values. `SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE LENGTH(string) < 20;` will not return rows where the string is 'NULL' for example.

Comment: @marc_s - OK understood - it is  empty string .  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, the `Remarks` column has no background color of *yellow* which indicates that it is not *NULL*. (*NULL values has.*)

It contains an empty string `''` (*or maybe spaces*) which is different from `NULL` because empty string is **set** as empty while `NULL` is not set (*nothing*).

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, the empty string is treated as NULL. SQL Server treats it as a string value.

The main difference is that in SQL Server you can return results from something like

```
select * from mytable where myfield = ''
```